# UITableView scrolling changess image inside UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, scroll

I am displaying some data using a `UITableViewController`, my table has 2 static sections with 6 static rows each. And I am subclassing `UITableViewCell` in order to add 3 Labels and a View, in the view I draw an arrow in only one of the cells in one of the sections.

This all goes perfectly fine. Till i scroll down... then the arrow is randomly placed in other cells, once i scroll back up the arrow has again changed cells... This also happens if i try to set a `backgroundColor` for only one of the cells. Once I scroll down and up the cell that originally had the color no longer has it, and another seemingly random cell has the color now.

Here is some of my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

TableViewCells *cell = (TableViewCells *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[TableViewCells alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];


return cell;
```

}

```
- (void)configureCell:(TableViewCells *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
    {
        if (indexPath.section == cotizacionIdeal)
        {
            cell.arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowUp.png"];
            [cell.nombre setText:@"Recursos"];
            [cell.cantidad setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f", [cotizacionPrevia.sueldoDeRecursos doubleValue]]];
            [cell.porcentaje setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f%@", [cotizacion.recursosPorcentaje doubleValue], @"%"]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.nombre setText:@"Recursos"];
            [cell.cantidad setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f", [cotizacionPrevia.sueldoDeRecursos doubleValue]]];
            [cell.porcentaje setText:[Calculate calcPorcentaje:cotizacionPrevia.sueldoDeRecursos totalReal:self.totalReal]];
        }
    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        if (indexPath.section == cotizacionIdeal)
        {
            [cell.nombre setText:@"Comision de Venta"];
            [cell.cantidad setText:[Calculate calcMonto:cotizacion.comisionPorcentaje total:self.totalIdeal]];
            [cell.porcentaje setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f%@", [cotizacion.comisionPorcentaje doubleValue], @"%"]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.nombre setText:@"Comision de Venta"];
            [cell.cantidad setText:self.montoRealComision];
            [cell.porcentaje setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f%@", [cotizacion.comisionPorcentaje doubleValue], @"%"]];
        }
    }
```

`UITableViewCell` class:

```
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame cell:(TableViewCells *)cell
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _cell = cell;

        //self.opaque = YES;
        //self.backgroundColor = _cell.backgroundColor;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [_cell.arrowImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}

@end

@implementation TableViewCells

@synthesize nombre;
@synthesize porcentaje;
@synthesize cantidad;
@synthesize arrowImage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialization code

        UILabel *nombreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.nombre = nombreLabel;
        [nombreLabel release];
        [self.nombre setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.nombre];

        UILabel *porcentajeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.porcentaje = porcentajeLabel;
        [porcentajeLabel release];
        [self.porcentaje setFont:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:10]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.porcentaje];

        UILabel *cantidadLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.cantidad = cantidadLabel;
        [self.cantidad setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
        [cantidadLabel release];
        [self.cantidad setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.cantidad];

        cellContentView = [[TableViewCellContentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero cell:self];
        cellContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellContentView];
    }
```

UPDATE:

I have also tried setting the image to a different one for everyone but one and I am still having the same issue.

```
- (void)configureCell:(TableViewCells *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowDown.png"];
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
    {
        if (indexPath.section == cotizacionIdeal)
        {
            cell.arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowUp.png"];
            [cell.nombre setText:@"Recursos"];
            [cell.cantidad setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f", [cotizacionPrevia.sueldoDeRecursos doubleValue]]];
            [cell.porcentaje setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f%@", [cotizacion.recursosPorcentaje doubleValue], @"%"]];
        }
        else
        {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that whenever you use drawRect for a cell you MUST call setneedsdisplay. That is what fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the UITableView reuses cells so that it doesn't need to make more instances than are displayed and you're not explicitly removing the arrow in your `configureCell` method.

If the arrow shouldn't be displayed on a cell, explicitly clear it out in the `configureCell` method and that should fix it.

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for your answer, I am aware that the viewcells are being reused and I have tried to explicitly clear the cell.arrowImage property by setting it to nil. However this is not working well. 

Even if i set different images for every single cell, once i scroll down and up the images are mixed up. I am setting my images in every cell the same way im setting them in the first one. How should I handle this issue?. Thank you in advance.

-Oscar

Comment: I have also tried this aproach

    - (void)configureCell:(TableViewCells *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 cell.arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowDown.png"];
 switch (indexPath.row) {
  case 0:
  {
   if (indexPath.section == cotizacionIdeal)
   {
    cell.arrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowUp.png"];
    [cell.nombre setText:@"Recursos"];
    [cell.cantidad setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f", [cotizacionPrevia.sueldoDeRecursos doubleValue]]];

Which works fine until i scroll down and up.

Comment: I am wondering could this be because I'm using the iphone simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% on this but I think it is to do with the release of the image. When you use imageNamed, the instance is retained so it is suggested to use imageWithFilePath instead.

Hope this helps....